# Is there a way to hide all panels in windows forms using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i was wondering if it was possible to hide everything at once in windows forms, i was planning to use a drop down which made things appear and disappear but i wanted everything hidden at the beginning for simplicity.
Thanks!

Comment: Iterate all controls in a form and set `Visible` to false.

Answer (score 0):

On the form, add a Panel control (found in the Containers section of the toolbox).

Set the Visible value of the Panel to be False.

Add all controls inside this panel. You can then make the panel visible and hidden via code. (no need to cycle through all controls on the form)